# SQL Server 2008 Dynamic Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, where-clause

Is it possible to have a dynamic where clause, based on the value of a column? I could use a case statement, but I need to have multiple values returned.  The pseudo-code would be below

E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS
CASE
    WHEN Location = 'Vegas'
    THEN 'WHERE FOO IN ('1','2','3')'
ELSE
    WHEN Location = 'Juneau'
    THEN 'WHERE FOO IN ('4','5','6')'
END
AND BUZZ = '1'
```

Comment: What is your table like and what do you want the output to look like ?

Comment: Fields: location, foo, fizz, buzz, price.

Example, select all prices: if Vegas then where foo is in (1,2,3), or if Juneau then where foo is in (4,5,6), else nothing

Comment: So, you want to get results based on certain values of Location AND Foo. The first answer shows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean logic:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS
where (
 (Location = 'Vegas' and FOO IN ('1','2','3')) or
 (Location = 'Juneau' and FOO IN ('4','5','6'))
)
AND BUZZ = '1'
```

Comment: Thanks blorgbeard, this makes sense. I'll test it to make sure it works, and mark this as answer if I'm not having any other issues